# Automator Apple Script - Conditional Rename/Delete

Tags: applescript, automator

I've been using automator to batch rename files and it's fantastic! Unfortunately, I now have a problem where every other image in a frame sequence needs to be renamed, and the ones in between deleted. I've come to the conclusion that I'll need an applescript with a conditional statement for the file name's number, but I haven't the slightest idea how to create one.

Basically, I have 60 frames which run at 60 fps, each with the extension ####. (for example, 0000, 0001, 0002, etc.) How can I convert the frames from 60 to 30, by deleting every other frame and renaming the rest to be sequential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use a shell script instead:

`rm *[13579].png; i=0; for f in *.png; do mv "$f" frame_$(printf %04d $i).png; ((i++)); done`

Comment: That looks cool. "rm *[13579].png;" (rm = remove file) removes all files with odd numbers and the residing file are "mv" (move files) moved/renamed correctly.  (BTW to OP: 'rm' removes items instantly - they are not in the trash -  so be conscious with testing)

Comment: Perfect answer - thanks to both of you. You've introduced me to Shell scripting, and where I thought automator was a lifesaver, Shell is a... lightsaber? Well, whatever it is, it's much better and extremely helpful. Thanks for your clarifications DigiMonk!

Comment: Your welcome. Lightsaber, sounds good, but I have the feeling it's more of an atomic bomb :) it's very important to type very carefully and have the perfect syntax especially with rm and * . Sometimes a space to much can delete everything and whatnot. Also, never use commands without checking first the manual: for that you have the "man" command (man= manual), so in Terminal.app you can always type "man rm" to see what command that is.